# Width and height of QGraphicsSvgItem

Tags: python, svg, height, pyqt4, qgraphicsitem

I believe this is simple question, but not for beginners as I am. My code is:

```
...
svg_file = QtCore.QFile('C:\svgTest.svg')
self.svgItem = QtSvg.QGraphicsSvgItem(svg_file.fileName())
...
```

How do I get width and height of self.svgItem?
I've tried this:

```
print self.svgItem.boundingRect()
```

and get:

```
PyQt4.QtCore.QRectF(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 383.0)
```

where "300" and "383" are values that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QRectF` objects have `height()` and `width()` methods.

So you can do:

```
br = self.svgItem.boundingRect()
w = br.width()
h = br.height()
```

See [the Qt documentation on QRectF](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qrectf.html) for details.